# Does it make sense to create a VM for each Minecraft-Server/JavaApp?

Tags: java, memory, virtual-machine, minecraft

I am fighting with a friend about the topic of Minecraft-Servers and other JavaApps and if it is a good idea to separate them into individual VMs.
But the point is, we´re not 100% sure which thoughts are right.
In the following I am going to list all ideas:

(highlited = pro)

> - manage and control CPU-/and Memory-Usage
> - easy backups

- Every Java-Process loads Libraries that can be used by another Process without loading it into RAM again
- Java-Processes, especially Minecraft-Servers can share Resources and can use this in a dynamic fashion

As we do not know which way is the best and due to the fact that Google does not know a good answer (which could indicate something) I decided to open this Question here.

Q: Does it make sense to keep Minecraft-Servers and other JavaApps in an individual VM ?

Comment: That's because there isn't an objective, general answer to this. It comes down to individual requirements

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert in Minecraft at all, however if it serves you as a guideline, in the past each web server run on its own JVM. Now the tendency is to run each micro service on its own JVM (and in turn each JVM in its own docker container). So, I'd say yes, run each Minecraft server on its own JVM.